# Testng opens only one browser for parallel config

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to run multiple tests in chrome. i.e 2 tests parallel in 2 chrome. I do have a maven project defined by the POM (testing.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="mytestsuite" parallel="tests" >
    <test name="case1">
        <classes>
            <class name="Testcases.hello1Test"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="case2">
        <classes>
            <class name="Testcases.hello2.Test"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Code to invoke browse is within my **baseTest** :

```
    public hello1Page1 hellopage1;
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
    DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    chromePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + prop.getProperty("driverrPath");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get(Prop.getProperty("URL"));

hellopage1 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, helloPage1.class);
```

**This is page class :**

```
public class hello1Page extends BaseTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    public  hello1Page(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public hello1Page method1 {... return this;}
    public hello1Page method2 {... return this;}
}
```

**This is test class :**

```
public class hello1Test extends BaseTest
{
    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void methodT1(){
            hello1page.method1();
    }
}
```

I have other tests that follow this same pattern.

What I am assuming is when I run `testng.xml`, It should go to baseTest 2 times and open 2 chrome then run my 2 tests in separate chrome. But somehow this is not happening. It opens only 1 chrome browser and run only 1 test.

Normally everything works fine like run single test case using maven command but issue is with parallel.

Comment: Probably best to share your tests code.

Comment: Please edit your question and include source code of how your test class and your base classes look like. What you have shared is not sufficient and doesnt give any idea in terms of what could be wrong here.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I added some code to get more idea.

Comment: What you have added still doesnt give a proper picture. Its not clear where or how your instantiation for the webdriver is happening. Can you please enrich it and make it a complete code (you can trim out what is not needed) but the code that you shared is not complete for taking a jab at it.

Comment: can you add thread-count="2"  before paralell in xml file

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting this is root cause

```
  hellopage1 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, helloPage1.class);
```

In BaseTest.

In Pages, declare

```
 WebDriver driver;
```

also

```
public className(WebDriver driver){

    this.driver = driver;

}
```

In Test Case

```
 WebDriver driver;

 PageClassName obj;


  @Test(priority=0)

public void test(){

    //Create Login Page object

objLogin = new PageClassName(driver);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if this is case then it should not run even single test case, correct?

Comment: it will run, in baseTest  there is driver but not properly on parallel tests.

Answer (score 0):

- List item
  Try with following steps :-

  1. Create Threadsafe Webdriver instance like this :

     private static ThreadLocal webDriver = new ThreadLocal();
  2. Use getter and setter to use driver like this :-

     public static WebDriver getDriver() {
     return webDriver.get();
     }

  static void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
      webDriver.set(driver);
  }

  3. Add thread-count=2  (TestNg xml file) like this :-

Hope this will help .Thank You! Refer this for more info - https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/